# Making Lists of **Pointers in c++

Tags: c++

What I was trying to do was make a list of them with

```
Item *itm = new Item();
_lst.push_front(&itm);
```

lst was made made in the header

```
std::list<int> _lst;
```

I am trying to learn c++ on my own so any advise would be great.

edit1)
doesn't &itm give the pointers location in memory which would be an int?

edit2)
The fact that i should not be learning c++ on my own does not help with the pointer problem

Comment: If it's a list of `int`, you're not going to have much luck putting an `Item**` on it...

Comment: You can learn C++ on your own, but without [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642), it won't be easy.

Comment: In response to your edit, **no**. Pointers are not `int`s. (In response to your other edit, you'd know that if you weren't learning C++ on your own...)

Comment: "The fact that i should not be learning c++ on my own does not help with the pointer problem" Yes it does. It tells you to forget your pointer problem and go read a book. Once you've done that, you'll look back on this question and know why not many think much of it. You said, "any advise would be great." There's my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest simply using

```
std::list<Item**> _lst;
```

Do you need the double indirection? Can't you do with a list like this:

```
std::list<Item*> _lst;
```

Of course, you'd have to push back `itm` instead of `&itm` if you wanted to do that. Are you sure you need a list and not a vector or a deque? As the comments suggested, get a good C++ book to help things along.

After reading the comment on my post by  R. Martinho Fernandes, I have to suggest `std::list<Item> _lst;` as a good alternative as well. It really depends on what you need, as I said earlier.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Or even better: `std::list<Item>`.

Comment: +1 @R.MartinhoFernandes is right - use pointers only when you really need them, and even then, there are often better alternatives than raw pointers (references and smart pointers come to mind).

Comment: Listen to the commenters. I have +1-ed both!